# jQuery not turning radio button off

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I don't understand why my radio button will, un-check, then check, but won't turn back off again. Can someone please help explain this? Here's my HTML:

```js
$('#member').click(() => {
  if ($('#member').attr('checked')) {
    $('#member').removeAttr('checked')
    $('#member').prop('checked', false)
  } else {
    /* $('#member').attr('checked') */
    $('#member').prop('checked', true)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="member" name="member" value="member" checked>
<label for="member">Member Reported</label><br>
```

Comment: Wouldn't a checkbox make more sense than a radio button?

Comment: It's the same behavior either way.

Comment: A radio will not uncheck unless one of the other options is checked, a checkbox will

Comment: @GertB. It unchecks the first time you click, but not after that.

Comment: @Barmar Radio buttons are meant to be used in groups, as defined by their sharing the same name attribute.

Comment: @Matt after first click `else` part of your code always run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bad idea to use single radio button. Radio buttons are meant to be used in groups, as defined by their sharing the same name attribute.

You can use checkbox for the purpose.

But if you insist on to know why your code works only for first time, the answer is:
**After first click `else` part of your code always run** because you never set `$('#member').attr('checked','checked');` in else part.

Comment: This was, in fact, my issue. I guess I though radio buttons and check boxes operated the same in HTML. I switched over to a checkbox and that was MUCH easier to deal with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just add the checked attribute back again like below

`$('#member').attr('checked','checked');`

```js
$('#member').click(() => {
    if($('#member').attr('checked')) { 
        $('#member').removeAttr('checked')
        $('#member').prop('checked',false)
    } else {
        $('#member').attr('checked','checked');
        $('#member').prop('checked',true);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="member" name="member" value="member" checked>
<label for="member" >Member Reported</label><br>
```